# How can I call a varargs function with an array in ActionScript?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I need to call a varargs function:

```
function doSomething(... args): Object {
    // do something with each arg
}
```

However, I'm building the arguments for this dynamically:

```
var someArgs: Array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
doSomething(someArgs);
```

The problem is, when I call the function in this way `args` ends up being a 1-element array with `someArgs` as the first element, not a three-element array.

How can I call `doSomething` with `someArgs` as the argument array?

(For the search engines, this is argument unpacking)

Comment: Note: this is called "argument unpacking". If you search google for that term as well as actionscript you will find a few discussions on the matter. Brian's suggestion to use .apply is correct IMO.

Comment: Congratulations, you are already #3 result on google under "actionscript argument unpacking" :)

Comment: Good lord.  SO.com really must be doing well, mm?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use Function.apply.

Like this:

```
doSomething.apply(null, someArgs);
```

If doSomething is a method of a class, pass in the class instead of null.

Comment: actually, it does not matter, whether you pass in the class/instance ... AS3 automatically creates method closures, where "this" is preassigned to always be the owner of the method ...

Comment: I ended up finding this about ten minutes after posting.  I figured I'd still provide rep to whomever answered, and it's nice to have it on SO.com.